# Seeking Help with Isomorphism Theorem and Ring Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I'm having some trouble solving these tasks:

Let R be an integral domain, $a \in R-\{0\}$ an element and $S:=\{a^n\}_{n \geq 0}\subset R$

a) Prove that the mapping $R[X]\rightarrow S^{-1}R$ given by $X \rightarrow \frac{1}{a}$ has an isomorphism $R[X]/(aX- 1)\rightarrow S^{-1}R$ induced.

b) Let p be a prime number and consider the ring

$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\{ \frac{x}{y}\in \mathbb{Q }: x,y \in \mathbb{Z} y\neq 0, y\equiv 0 \text{ mod p} \}$

Show that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a principal ideal ring but not a field.

for a) I wanted to solve the exercise using the
Isomorphism theorem.

$f:X \rightarrow \frac{1}{a}$ is a surjective homomorphism.

If we prove that $(aX-1)=ker(f)$ we can use the isomorphism theorem and we have solved the exercise, right? But I am having problems showing $(aX-1)=ker(f)$, can someone help me? Is it the right way to solve this problem?

For b) I think, that I have shown correctly that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a principal ideal ring:

We have a principal ideal ring if every ideal $I\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is generated by a $d \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal ring we have that for every $a=\frac{x}{y} \in I$ that $a=\frac{rd}{y}=\frac{r}{y}d$ also it is generated by $(d)$ and $\frac{r}{y} \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$

Have I done it right?

For showing that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is not a field I thought to show that it exists al least an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ which is not invertible, but I have no idea on hoe to show this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your idea for (a) sounds fine, but what is $S$?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to write a part of the problem. I have updated the question @user920957

Comment: For (a) it suffices to show: "$f\in R[x]$. Then viwed as an element if $Frac(R)[x]$, $f(\frac{1}{a})=0\implies$ in $R[x]$ $(ax-1)|\ f(x)$". In $R[x]$ there is no Euclideaan division. But what if we start "at tail"? If $f(x)=u_nx^n+\cdots+u_1x+u_0$, then $f(x)-u_0(ax-1)=u_nx^n+\cdots+(u_1-au_0)x$ is a polynomial admitting $\frac{1}{a}$ as zero viewed as a polynomial in $Frac[x]$ (since $\frac{1}{a}$ is both zero of $f$ and $u_0(ax-1)$). Then we may let $(u_1-au_0)x$ vanish by constructing $f(x)-u_0(ax-1)-(u_1-au_0)x(ax-1)$. $\cdots$

Comment: ...and for (b), $p+1$ is not invertible.

Comment: @Asigan and can we solve the problem with the isomorphism theorem as I was doing?

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo Yes. $\ker f=\{g\in R[x]\ |\ g(\frac{1}{a})=0\}$, and my previous argument shows $\{g\in R[x]\ |\ g(\frac{1}{a})=0\}=(ax-1)$. Therefore the isomorphism theorem says $$S^{-1}R\cong R[X]/\ker f=R[x]/\{g\in R[x]\ |\ g(\frac{1}{a})=0\}=R/(ax-1).$$ (Sorry I did not realized $f$ already denots the homomorphism when I wrote the previous comment.)